# Git merge commit missing

Tags: git

I'm seeking for an explanation of following:

My git repository is on stash.

I have 2 branches: master, develop.
Today I wanted to release a new version, for this reason I created **release-1.0** branch from a **develop branch**.

Then I did:

git checkout release-1.0
updated the poms to release version
git commit -m "Prepare poms for next release"
git push
git merge master //to be sure if everything is in sync

Next using stash i created a pull request. My mate accepted it and everything went to master and the commit appeared:
**9c08cd5fc435 Merge pull request #1 in XXX from release-1.0 to master**

The last thing to do was to update the develop branch with those changes
so I did:

git checkout develop
git merge master
git status

//here I saw all the poms that have changed

git commit -m "Merge back release changes to develop"
git push

And here the magic happened - **git did not record this last commit**.

When I list the commits for **develop** branch I can see that git somehow embedded the last commit from the **release branch** i.e. **"Prepare poms for next release"**, but there is nothing like **"Merge back release changes to develop"**

Can anyone explain me this strange situation?

Comment: Try reading [this](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/09/fast-forward-git-merge.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no changes to commit at the moment you execute...

```
git commit -m "Merge back release changes to develop"
```

If you really wish to makes an (empty) commit with this message, you can do

```
git commit -m "Merge back release changes to develop" --allow-empty
```

What is happening is the following: Your master is simply a number of commits ahead of your develop branch. If you merge master into develop, what you are actually doing is making the pointer "develop" point to a different commit (the same as master) without making an actual new commit.

Git tells you this as follows:

```
Fast-forward
```

Comment: Thanks Bart this seems to be the case.